# CSS patio layout

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a patio layout with tiles (hurray tiles!) which allows for different sizes intermingled. To do this I just have a load of `<article>`'s which I float left and they naturally fall into place. This works fine until I start getting fancy with vertical shapes.

I have a gap at the bottom, how do I fill it? I tried swapping some boxes around but this didn't help. See below for pic, code and JSFiddle links.

[image: Patio Layout]

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <article class="oneXone">
        hello world
    </article>

    <article class="oneXone">
        hello world
    </article>

    <article class="twoXone rhs">
        hello world
    </article>

    <article class="threeXone">
        hello world
    </article>

    <article class="oneXone rhs">
        hello world
    </article>

    <article class="oneXtwo">
        hello world
    </article>

    <article class="twoXone">
        hello world
    </article>

    <article class="oneXtwo rhs">
        hello world
    </article>

    <article class="oneXone">
        hello world
    </article>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container { width: 480px; } 
article { float: left; margin: 0 8px 8px 0; padding: 5px; background: red; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
.rhs { margin-right: 0; }
.floatRight { float: right; }
.oneXone { width: 114px; height: 114px; }
.twoXone { width: 236px; height: 114px; }
.threeXone { width: 358px; height: 114px; }
.oneXtwo { width: 114px; height: 236px; }
.oneXthree { width: 114px; height: 358px; }
.twoXtwo { width: 236px; height: 236px; }
```

[Original JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykQBr/)

[Swapped boxes around JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykQBr/1/)

Comment: Try [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). I know it's not a pure CSS solution, but it's about the best solution I know of for this kind of thing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ykQBr/2/

Comment: You should add this as an answer @AldiUnanto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay **Chris Nicholson**, as your request this is my answer.

add a `class` of particular tag, like 'a'.

`<article class="oneXone a">
        hello world
    </article>`

Then, css :

```
.a{
    background-color: #1361aa;
    margin: -122px 0 0 122px;
    width: 236px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ykQBr/2/

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your **CSS**:

```
.oneXone:last-child {
    margin: -122px 0 0 122px;
    width: 114px;
}
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/ykQBr/7/)** with two blocks fit inside.

Comment: mark this as *answered* if you are satisfied with the solution

Comment: This will only work if the layout will remain the same and nothing is dynamic, also this was in the comments

Comment: Slightly different, but overall yes.
As you can see the user has chosen to use specific width and height.
For dynamic values there are always % and em which can be easily substituted.

Comment: In the OP's question _which allows for random sizes intermingled._

Comment: Just to clear up any confusion, this method probably would work for me, as I do have complete control over the boxes, their sizes and their order - it's essentially a static layout (by random I only mean there will be *different* sizes, not randomly generated, I'll amend the OP to say this). I'd be interested to know the possible browser issues associated with this, are negative margins like this well supported?

Comment: Yes they are.  However this is a very inflexible solution.  I would recommend going with a JS library like Masonry.

Comment: I had a quick look at what Masonry does, all it seems to do is calculate the position of everything and absolute position boxes relative to a parent container. As I've said, I have complete control and things don't change so I *could* just hard code that myself.